# Teaching report writer

Tags: json, variables

I have alreday created a simple webpage which allows me to select a variety of statements which I enter for a school report. It's working, however it seems to restrict the number of characters in the report.

I've also attempted to create two new options and outcomes so that more sentences can be added. It's not working. I'd also like it to appear on one page though my coding knowledge is limited and has been supported by ai and I don't have these skills.

Here's my new attempted code - which isn't working.

Here's the live version which is partially working, other than the text limit and the extra options.
https://www.rhythmstix.co.uk/reportwriter/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Report Helper</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #3366cc;
    }

    h2 {
      color: #339933;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    select {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #3366cc;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:hover {
      background-color: #24568c;
    }

    #commentBankList li {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #selectedOutcomes h3 {
      color: #339933;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #reportTextarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var commentBanks = [];

    function addCommentBank() {
      var commentText = document.getElementById('commentText').value.trim();
      var option = document.getElementById('option').value;

      if (commentText !== '') {
        var commentEntry = option + ': ' + commentText;
        commentBanks.push(commentEntry);
        document.getElementById('commentText').value = '';
        updateCommentBankList();
        saveCommentBanks();
      }
    }

    function updateCommentBankList() {
      var commentBankList = document.getElementById('commentBankList');
      commentBankList.innerHTML = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < commentBanks.length; i++) {
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.textContent = commentBanks[i];
        commentBankList.appendChild(listItem);
      }
    }

    function saveCommentBanks() {
      localStorage.setItem('commentBanks', JSON.stringify(commentBanks));
    }

    function loadCommentBanks() {
      var storedCommentBanks = localStorage.getItem('commentBanks');
      if (storedCommentBanks) {
        commentBanks = JSON.parse(storedCommentBanks);
        updateCommentBankList();
      }
    }

    function generateReport() {
      var reportTextarea = document.getElementById('reportTextarea');
      var childName = document.getElementById('childName').value.trim();
      var yearGroup = document.getElementById('yearGroup').value.trim();

      var selectedComments = '';
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        var comment = checkbox.value.split(', ')[0].replace('#N', childName);
        selectedComments += comment + '\n';
      });

      var commentBankEntries = '';

      // Iterate over checkboxes for outcomes 1 to 5
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var outcomeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-outcome="Outcome ' + i + '"]:checked');
        outcomeCheckboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
          var optionNumber = checkbox.value.split(', ')[1]; // Extract the option number from the value
          var commentIndex = parseInt(optionNumber) - 1; // Convert option number to array index
          var comment = commentBanks[commentIndex]; // Get the comment from the comment bank
          if (comment) { // Ensure comment exists before appending
            commentBankEntries += comment + '\n'; // Append comment to the report
          }
        });
      }

      var finalReport = 'Child Name: ' + childName + '\nYear Group: ' + yearGroup + '\n\nSelected Comments:\n' + selectedComments.trim() + '\n';

      if (commentBankEntries !== '') {
        finalReport += 'Comment Bank Entries:\n' + commentBankEntries.trim();
      }

      reportTextarea.value = finalReport;
    }

    function copyReport() {
      var reportTextarea = document.getElementById('reportTextarea');
      reportTextarea.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      alert('Report copied to clipboard!');
    }

    function clearCommentBank() {
      commentBanks = [];
      updateCommentBankList();
      saveCommentBanks();
    }

    function clearReport() {
      document.getElementById('childName').value = '';
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = false;
      });
      document.getElementById('reportTextarea').value = '';
    }

    function importCommentBanks() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('commentBankFileInput');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var importedCommentBanks = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        commentBanks = importedCommentBanks;
        updateCommentBankList();
        saveCommentBanks();
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function exportCommentBanks() {
      var yearGroup = document.getElementById('yearGroup').value.trim();
      var filename = 'comment_banks_' + yearGroup + '.json';
      var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(commentBanks, null, 2);
      var blob = new Blob([jsonContent], { type: 'application/json' });

      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = filename;
      link.click();
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadCommentBanks);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Report Helper</h1>

  <h2>Year Group</h2>
  <label for="yearGroup">Year Group:</label>
  <input type="text" id="yearGroup"><br><br>

  <h2>Child Information</h2>
  <label for="childName">Child's Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="childName"><br><br>

  <h2>Comment Bank</h2>
  <div id="commentBank">
    <label for="commentText">Add Comment:</label>
    <textarea id="commentText"></textarea>
    <select id="option">
      <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="addCommentBank()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="clearCommentBank()">Clear Comments</button>
    <ul id="commentBankList"></ul>
  </div><br>

  <h2>Selected Outcomes</h2>
  <div id="selectedOutcomes">
    <!-- Outcome 1 -->
    <h3>Outcome 1</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 1" data-outcome="Outcome 1"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 2" data-outcome="Outcome 1"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 3" data-outcome="Outcome 1"> Option 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 4" data-outcome="Outcome 1"> Option 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 5" data-outcome="Outcome 1"> Option 5<br><br>

    <!-- Outcome 2 -->
    <h3>Outcome 2</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 1" data-outcome="Outcome 2"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 2" data-outcome="Outcome 2"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 3" data-outcome="Outcome 2"> Option 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 4" data-outcome="Outcome 2"> Option 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 5" data-outcome="Outcome 2"> Option 5<br><br>

    <!-- Outcome 3 -->
    <h3>Outcome 3</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 1" data-outcome="Outcome 3"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 2" data-outcome="Outcome 3"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 3" data-outcome="Outcome 3"> Option 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 4" data-outcome="Outcome 3"> Option 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 5" data-outcome="Outcome 3"> Option 5<br><br>

    <!-- Outcome 4 -->
    <h3>Outcome 4</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 4, Option 1" data-outcome="Outcome 4"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 4, Option 2" data-outcome="Outcome 4"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 4, Option 3" data-outcome="Outcome 4"> Option 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 4, Option 4" data-outcome="Outcome 4"> Option 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 4, Option 5" data-outcome="Outcome 4"> Option 5<br><br>
    
    <!-- Outcome 5 -->
    <h3>Outcome 5</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 5, Option 1" data-outcome="Outcome 5"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 5, Option 2" data-outcome="Outcome 5"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 5, Option 3" data-outcome="Outcome 5"> Option 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 5, Option 4" data-outcome="Outcome 5"> Option 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 5, Option 5" data-outcome="Outcome 5"> Option 5<br><br>
  </div>

  <button onclick="generateReport()">Generate Report</button>
  <button onclick="clearReport()">Clear Report</button>
  <button onclick="copyReport()">Copy Report</button><br><br>

  <h2>Report</h2>
  <textarea id="reportTextarea"></textarea><br>

  <h2>Import/Export Comment Banks</h2>
  <input type="file" id="commentBankFileInput" accept=".json">
  <button onclick="importCommentBanks()">Import Comment Banks</button>
  <button onclick="exportCommentBanks()">Export Comment Banks</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the original code, which is working apart from the text restriction which doesn't seem to be able to allow longer sentences:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Teaching Report Writer - Music</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #3366cc;
    }

    h2 {
      color: #339933;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    select {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #3366cc;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:hover {
      background-color: #24568c;
    }

    #commentBankList li {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #selectedOutcomes h3 {
      color: #339933;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #reportTextarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var commentBanks = [];

    function addCommentBank() {
      var commentText = document.getElementById('commentText').value.trim();
      var option = document.getElementById('option').value;

      if (commentText !== '') {
        var commentEntry = option + ': ' + commentText;
        commentBanks.push(commentEntry);
        document.getElementById('commentText').value = '';
        updateCommentBankList();
        saveCommentBanks();
      }
    }

    function updateCommentBankList() {
      var commentBankList = document.getElementById('commentBankList');
      commentBankList.innerHTML = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < commentBanks.length; i++) {
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.textContent = commentBanks[i];
        commentBankList.appendChild(listItem);
      }
    }

    function saveCommentBanks() {
      localStorage.setItem('commentBanks', JSON.stringify(commentBanks));
    }

    function loadCommentBanks() {
      var storedCommentBanks = localStorage.getItem('commentBanks');
      if (storedCommentBanks) {
        commentBanks = JSON.parse(storedCommentBanks);
        updateCommentBankList();
      }
    }

function generateReport() {
  var reportTextarea = document.getElementById('reportTextarea');
  var childName = document.getElementById('childName').value.trim();
  var yearGroup = document.getElementById('yearGroup').value.trim();

  var selectedComments = '';
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
    var comment = checkbox.value.split(', ')[0].replace('#N', childName);
    selectedComments += comment + '\n';
  });

  var commentBankList = document.getElementById('commentBankList');
  var commentBankItems = commentBankList.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var commentBankEntries = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < commentBankItems.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[i];
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      var comment = commentBankItems[i].textContent.split(': ')[1].replace('#N', childName);
      commentBankEntries += comment + ' ';
    }
  }

  var finalReport = 'Child Name: ' + childName + '\nYear Group: ' + yearGroup + '\n\nSelected Comments:\n' + selectedComments.trim() + '\n';

  if (commentBankEntries !== '') {
    finalReport += 'Comment Bank Entries:\n' + commentBankEntries.trim();
  }

  reportTextarea.value = finalReport;
}

    function copyReport() {
      var reportTextarea = document.getElementById('reportTextarea');
      reportTextarea.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      alert('Report copied to clipboard!');
    }

    function clearCommentBank() {
      commentBanks = [];
      updateCommentBankList();
      saveCommentBanks();
    }

    function clearReport() {
      document.getElementById('childName').value = '';
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = false;
      });
      document.getElementById('reportTextarea').value = '';
    }

    function importCommentBanks() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('commentBankFileInput');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var importedCommentBanks = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        commentBanks = importedCommentBanks;
        updateCommentBankList();
        saveCommentBanks();
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function exportCommentBanks() {
      var yearGroup = document.getElementById('yearGroup').value.trim();
      var filename = 'comment_banks_' + yearGroup + '.json';
      var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(commentBanks, null, 2);
      var blob = new Blob([jsonContent], { type: 'application/json' });

      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = filename;
      link.click();
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadCommentBanks);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Teaching Report Writer - Music</h1>

  <h2>Year Group</h2>
  <label for="yearGroup">Year Group:</label>
  <input type="text" id="yearGroup"><br><br>

  <h2>Child Information</h2>
  <label for="childName">Child's Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="childName"><br><br>

  <h2>Comment Bank</h2>
  <div id="commentBank">
    <label for="commentText">Add Comment:</label>
    <textarea id="commentText"></textarea>
    <select id="option">
      <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="addCommentBank()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="clearCommentBank()">Clear Comments</button>
    <ul id="commentBankList"></ul>
  </div><br>

  <h2>Selected Outcomes</h2>
  <div id="selectedOutcomes">
    <!-- Outcome 1 -->
    <h3>Outcome 1</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 1"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 2"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 1, Option 3"> Option 3<br><br>

    <!-- Outcome 2 -->
    <h3>Outcome 2</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 1"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 2"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 2, Option 3"> Option 3<br><br>

    <!-- Outcome 3 -->
    <h3>Outcome 3</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 1"> Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 2"> Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Outcome 3, Option 3"> Option 3<br><br>
  </div>

  <button onclick="generateReport()">Generate Report</button>
  <button onclick="clearReport()">Clear Report</button>
  <button onclick="copyReport()">Copy Report</button><br><br>

  <h2>Report</h2>
  <textarea id="reportTextarea"></textarea><br>

  <h2>Import/Export Comment Banks</h2>
  <input type="file" id="commentBankFileInput" accept=".json">
  <button onclick="importCommentBanks()">Import Comment Banks</button>
  <button onclick="exportCommentBanks()">Export Comment Banks</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to increase the options to 5 in comment band and the selected outcome.